# Can't get power button symbol right. Need help cutting letter 'O' and filling gaps

Tags: mesh

I'm having trouble making a 3d power button symbol. I want it to look similar to [this](http://3dicon-free.com/highresolution/l_092.png) one. [Here](https://mega.co.nz/#!N1pwET4Z!iP2pzrHoA6JsqudLKbpRH509y6zHC5Zgp0duyM8gSfc) is the .blend file I'm working with, if this helps anyone understand what I'm trying to do.
Using the cuboid that's over the letter 'o', I can cut out the portion of the letter 'o' that the cuboid occupies, however, the remaining ends of the letter 'o' are left open.
I can't find a way to fill the ends, and preferably round the ends. If anyone can show me how to do this, that would be a great help!

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is how you can create a power button:

1. Add a circle.
2. Enter edit mode.
3. Selected it(<kbd>A</kbd>) and extrude + scale it inwards.
4. Delete(<kbd>X</kbd>->Faces) some of the at the top of the circle as such:
   [image]
5. Add a plane into the scene.
6. scale the plane so that it takes the shape of the line:
   [image]
7. Select All(<kbd>A</kbd>), and extrude it upwards until your power button is as thick as you want it.
8. To add rounded edges: select the line, as well as the faces on the inside of the cut. also select the rings(<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>) that make up the edges of the '0'.
9. With all those vertices selected hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>B</kbd>. Use the scroll wheel to control the amount of cuts(I'd recommend 4).
10. Select all and hit <kbd>W</kbd>->Shade Smooth.
11. Rotate it on the Y axis to 90 degrees (<kbd>R</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd><kbd>90</kbd>) .

Done!